# "Adding folders" marked as a duplicate of "Adding item" to Explorer sidebar

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I recently asked this question, [How to add Google Drive to the Windows Explorer Sidebar](https://superuser.com/questions/883424/how-to-add-google-drive-to-the-windows-explorer-sidebar) and it was marked as a duplicate before anyone who could answer it saw it.

My question was not answered by the answers provided in the master question.

What can I do about this? No one can answer a question closed as a duplicate, and I already edited it.

Honestly, it feels like the high rep users just breeze though the queues and mark things as duplicates without thinking. It doesn't make a low rep user want to stay.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been re-opened.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :)